# Loading NSString class on iOS fails, while NSSet and other works?

Tags: ctypes, pyobjc, bridging-header

Using ctypes, I am getting a handle for objc_getClass method, and then I am trying to locate NSString but it FAILS!! At the same time, other classes such as NSSet/NSMutableArray and so on just work great!

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll

c = cdll.LoadLibrary(None)
objc_getClass = c.objc_getClass

>>> c.objc_getClass(b'NSSet')
-110110920
>>> c.objc_getClass(b'NSString')
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because the Foundation framework is not loaded.

Try adding this before trying to resolve classes:

```
cdll.LoadLibrary('/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation')
```